# How to repair a [Segmentation fault] in parallelizing a for loop with OpenMP?

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, openmp

I'm getting a segmentation fault in my attempt to parallelize a `for`-loop and I'm not being able to understand why.

Here's the code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:ptx,pty)
    for(int i=0;i<numSteps;i++)
    {
        float energy=0;
        for(int idx=0;idx<patternNum;idx++)
        {
            float hitColor = getInterpolatedElement31(frame->dI,
                                        (float)(ptx+rotatetPattern[idx][0]),
                                        (float)(pty+rotatetPattern[idx][1]),
                                        wG[0]);

            if(!std::isfinite(hitColor)) {energy+=1e5; continue;}

            float residual = hitColor - (float)(hostToFrame_affine[0] * color[idx] + hostToFrame_affine[1]);
            float hw = fabs(residual) < setting_huberTH ? 1 : setting_huberTH / fabs(residual);
            energy += hw *residual*residual*(2-hw);
        }

        if(debugPrint)
            printf("step %.1f %.1f (id %f): energy = %f!\n",
                    ptx, pty, 0.0f, energy);

        errors[i] = energy;
        if(energy < bestEnergy)
        {
            bestU = ptx; bestV = pty; bestEnergy = energy; bestIdx = i;
        }

        ptx+=dx;
        pty+=dy;
    }
std::cout << "hello\n";
```

The function, where this `for`-loop is in, is called many times, and the segmentation fault is only caused **after** many iterations of this function.

That's why I put the `cout << "hello"`, to see how many many times the `"hello"` was printed.

However, even though the first few iterations generated no error, I think the results for the calculations being performed are not correct, this is a SLAM code, so in the output I can see that the results, before I get the segmentation fault, are not what it was supposed to be.

Can you see anything in this loop that is could generate this error using this pragma?

Comment: Please convert the code into a [mcve] and explain the result of your own debugging effort.

Comment: Does the code run without errors and does it give correct results in serial? Your first sentence sounds like it does but it is not fully clear for me.

Comment: @Shadow yes it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I believe reduction(+:ptx,pty) is not what you need. Serial code supposes ptx and pty are incremented for each next iteration because their values are used in getInterpolatedElement31 call. But with reduction you will have the same value on each iteration = initial value of ptx (pty).

Second, shared variables *bestU*, *bestV*, *bestEnergy*, *bestIdx* might be updated by several threads simultaneosly

```
bestU = ptx; bestV = pty; bestEnergy = energy; bestIdx = i;
```

So, you need some synchronization here.

Comment: You are right @Milad Rashidi , segmentation fault was caused by the reduction clause. Although now that i dont have a segmentation fault, this parallelization doesn't give me the right results. I add a pragma omp critical to that line that you said needed synchronization, but still have bad results

Comment: Have you changed `ptx+=dx; pty+=dy; ` accordingly that they were different on each iteration?

Comment: i haven't changed that no. But now that you point that out and i think about it, maybe this loop is not parallelizable, each iteration is dependent on the previous due to that change on ptx and pty values right?

Answer (score -1):

> *in the output I can see that **the results**, before I get the segmentation fault, **are not what it was supposed to be.***

Well, it would be fair to review a problem on content-wise correctly working code. Yet, let me sketch a few tips on where the principal problems may appear, or how to use a stone-age strategy to frame the root-cause...

It is a common practice to have a data-set with a known solution, so as to early detect error / confirm the validity of the process design on the results produced, just by re-running the know test-set.

---

> *getting a segmentation fault ... and I'm not being able to understand **why**.*

**General suspects are:**
declaration / addressing related, as seen in:
**`idx`** `== patternNum - 1` : **`rotatetPattern[idx]`**`[ {0|1} ]`
**`idx`** `== patternNum - 1` : **`color[idx]`**
**`i`**  `== numStep` : **`errors[i]`**
**`?`**  `hostToFrame_affine`**`[]`**
**`?`**  `wG`**`[]`**

calling signature(s) and/or implementation details, as seen in:
`float` `getInterpolatedElement31`**`(...){ ... }`**
`float` `fabs`**`( ... ){ ... }`**

---

### The easiest next step ? Watch the smoking-gun trails first ... always ...

The simplest step available right now is to add a DEBUG-trailing-stop line after each executed line:

```
FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( 0 ); // ------------------------------------------------

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:ptx,pty)
    for( int i =  0;
             i <  numSteps;
             i++
             )
    {   
        FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( 1 ); // ----------------------------------------

        float energy = 0;

        FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( 2 ); // ----------------------------------------

        for ( int idx =  0;
                  idx <  patternNum;
                  idx++
                  )
        {   FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( 3 ); // ------------------------------------

            float hitColor = getInterpolatedElement31(
                                         frame->dI,
                                 (float)( ptx
                                        + rotatetPattern[idx][0]
                                          ),
                                 (float)( pty
                                        + rotatetPattern[idx][1]
                                          ),
                                        wG[0]
                                 );

            FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( 4 ); // -----------------------------------

            if ( !std::isfinite( hitColor ) )
            {    
                  FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( 5 ); // -----------------------------

                  energy += 1e5;

                  FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( 6 ); // -----------------------------

                  continue;

                  FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( 7 ); // -------------------------- ;)
            }

            float residual = hitColor
                           - (float) ( hostToFrame_affine[0]
                                     * color[idx]
                                     + hostToFrame_affine[1]
                                       );

            FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( 8 ); // -----------------------------------

            float hw = setting_huberTH > fabs( residual )
                     ? 1
                     : setting_huberTH / fabs( residual );

            FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( 9 ); // -----------------------------------

            energy += hw
                    * residual
                    * residual
                    * ( 2 - hw );

            FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( 10 ); // ----------------------------------

        }

        FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( 11 ); // --------------------------------------
        ...
        ..
        .
```

Using :

```
        void FLINTSTONEs_DEBUG_LOG( int TracePOINT )
        {    printf( "ACK: thread[%d]'s smoke-trail has reached TracePOINT( %d )\n",
                     omp_get_thread_num(),
                     TracePOINT
                     );
        }
```

Sure, this is no rocket-science, but may easily show you the smoke-trail after the next SegFault appeared in print, so guess worth mention it here too.

Yabba Dabba Doo, go get it rock-solid running, one step after another.